# Orchard CMS Alternate shape for editortemplate of the title part?

Tags: templates, orchardcms, shapes

I have a content type that I need to make the title non editable for - what is the correct name for the alternate shape cshtml file?

I have placed a copy of the Title/Views/EditorTemplates/Parts.Title.TitlePart.cshtml into my own Views/EditorTemplates directory (same filename, different content) but it's not picked up. I've also tried Parts.Title.TitlePart-MyContentTypeName.cshtml in the same directory but that's also not shown instead of the core shape.

Although I've tweaked the Shape Tracer module code to show in within the Admin panel, it doesn't seem to be drilling down and showing me each of the parts on the page (Title, Autoroute, Body etc) - instead it's displaying:

```
Shape: EditorTemplate
Active Template: Orchard.Core.Shapes.CoreShapes::EditorTemplate
Display Type: n/a
​Alternate (3) 
 Create ~/Themes/TheAdmin/Views/EditorTemplate.cshtml
 Create ~/Themes/TheAdmin/Views/EditorTemplate-12.cshtml
 Create ~/Themes/TheAdmin/Views/EditorTemplate-Store.cshtml
Wrappers (0)
```

What am I getting wrong? I want to display a greyed out textbox with the hint changed to "you cannot change the title of this item"

Cheers!

Comment: This alternate seems to work for me: MyTheme/Views/EditorTemplates/Parts.Title.TitlePart.cshtml

Comment: This approach looks wrong to me: you are disabling the UI, but the driver is still accepting changes, so you could very easily craft a post that would change the title. I think you need a different part. It can implement ITitle.